# Escape-code "^[[43;1R" breaks my bash-expect script execution

Tags: bash, expect, ansi-escape

I'm really young in linux and bash\expect scripting and i searched information for a days, but still don't have a solution.

This is my bash script with some expect blocks:

```
#!/bin/bash

expect <(cat <<'EOF'
set timeout -1
spawn $env(SHELL)
expect "#" {
send "(./(installation.sh) my_argument)\r"
}
expect {
    "*Accept this solution?*" {
        send -- "y\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "*Do you want to continue?*" {
        send -- "y\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "*Would you like to setup prompt server reservation using rsync?*" {
        sleep 1
        send -- "N;\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "*Your choice*" {
        sleep 1
        send -- "\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "*Enter a list of hosts which should be available to the database*" {
        sleep 1
        send -- "127.0.0.1;\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "*Do you want to continue?*" {
        send -- "y\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "#" {
    }
}
EOF
)
```

It spawns an another installation.sh script that installs some common packages and out propriatary soft.

It works well exсept one place:
While installation.sh executing, terminal asks "YOUR CHOICE" that have a 3 variant of answer - 'del' to delete some host, 'add' to add new, ENTER to continue (see attached screenshots).[enter pushing moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwgV2.png)

I need give the ENTER pushing for doing nothing and continue script execution (i do it with send -- "\r"), but when terminal gives some output like "^[[43;1R" that break execution and stop script some minutes after that.

And when last literally 2 lines of executing before the end it stops.[stop-moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqfH9.png)

If anyone can help i will be very appreciate!

I tried to fix that with doing, but it doesn't help:

1. replaced send -- "\r" with send -- "\n"
2. changed file format with dos2unix to unix format to avoid DOS endings

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) `./$env(installation.sh)` definitely looks like a syntax error; which shell accepts this sort of syntax?

Comment: `<(cat <<'EOF'` is similarly crazy. I guess you simply mean `<<'EOF'` and take out the closing parenthesis?

Comment: First of all, I would not embed such a huge amout of Tcl code inside a bash program. Split it into one Tcl file and one bash file. It will also make debugging easier. As for your problem at hand: The program you are driving embeds escape codes for formatting (colouring...) into its output. My advice is to find that person who writes this script and tell him that he either should not do this, or make this an option, so that you can use the program without this "feature".  Otherwise  [filter the output](https://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream).

Comment: @tripleee: Syntactically, the OP wants to write Tcl code here, but even then it is semantically weird, as it would substitute the content of an environment variable named `installation.sh`.

Comment: @user1934428 It is not formatting Escape code. That is a position report. It is not a code that goes from the script to the terminal. It is a report, that goes from the terminal to the script (Most escape code are sent as a `print`: you `print('^[[31m')`, and instead of printing that, the terminal understand it as an instruction to change color of future prints. But some are sent by the terminal, as it already send keycodes. You `scanf("%s",str)`, see some `^[[12;5R` in str, and understand that the user did not really typed that, but that the terminal send it to say something)

Comment: In this case, that "something" is "cursor position is at column 1, line 43 of the terminal". Not that it really matters. But what do matters, is that it is not the program that sent this `^[[43;1R` code. It is the terminal that did. Now, the reason why it did, of course, is because it receives an instruction to do it. For example with `^[[6n` code, that ask for such a "report". But I wouldn't rule out that it is `expect` itself that send some `^[[6n`. It makes sense for such an automation script to need to know where the cursor is.

Comment: Those terminal characters are not breaking your expect program. Expect sees them as simple characters. They are not part of any pattern your expect to see and you are not capturing the output in any way. As to why your script hangs at the end: the installation process does not exit and return to your shell prompt. Perhaps it's still working on the install. The only code review issue I see are the duplicated "Do you want to continue" block, the (possibly) unnecessary sleeps and the useless use of cat. `send "\r"` is the correct way to "hit enter".

Comment: @glennjackman : That's what I meant by "breaking". The Expect script is not prepared to see these, and does not handle them. Of course one could put handling of those characters into the Tcl code, but IMO this would be bad style: A program should output ANSI codes only if it is supposed to talk to a terminal which is interpreting them. Reasonable programs either don't emit them if stdout is not a terminal, or allow those codes to be disabled by a switch. That's why I propose to handle this problem outside of the Expect program.

Comment: @chrslg : If this is code sent from the Terminal to the screen, I first don't understand why the Tcl code is "seeing" this. And then, such a code can be sent from the terminal only as a response to a request sent from a script (for instance, to enquire the terminal size), and IMO, a program should send such requests only if they really talk to a terminal

Comment: Try `TERM=dumb` to remove escape sequences

Comment: I'd suggest that expect does not need to handle them at all. You don't handle every single character that the installation produces. These terminal characters aren't any different. _Unless_ that installation process relies on them

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano i expotred TERM=dumb and probled has gone.
thanks a lot, this way helped me!